# Save dictionary of class instances in a file?

Tags: python, dictionary, persistent-storage

Consider following class and function:

```
class DictEntry:
    term = ""
    docFreq = 0
    termFreq = 0
    postingList = []

    def __init__(self, t, df, tf, pl):
        self.term = t
        self.docFreq = df
        self.termFreq = tf
        self.postingList = pl

def insertDict(docId, token, termFreq, dictionary):
    entry = dictionary.get(token)
    if entry is None:
        postList = []
        entry = DictEntry(token, 0, 0, postList)
        dictionary[token] = entry
    entry.docFreq +=1
    entry.postingList.extend([docId])
    entry.termFreq += termFreq
```

The function `insertDict` creates an object for a key if it's not in dictionary.

In main, I need to save `dictionary` with keys and class instances to a file.

Comment: Try useing `pickle`

Comment: Just a note... Keep in mind that the `term` attribute shown right under `class DictEntry:` is different than the `term` in the `__init__` (where you do `self.term = t`). The ones under the `class DictEntry:` belong to the `__class__` and are like Java's `static` (every instance will get the same attributes), whereas the one in the `__init__` are linked to the `__dict__` attribute of the **instance**, and each instance will have its own (what I mean is that I would remove the declaration of the four attributes under `class DictEntry`)